# Angular performance with ng-if="!!someVar" vs ng-if="someVar"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I was just wondering if one can gain better performance using `ng-if="!!someVar"` where `someVar` is an object that either is defined or undefined instead of `ng-if="someVar"`. Both clearly work in Angular JS I was wondering what is easier for javascript and angular to evaluate?

In summary, which is the best way to write the ng-if directive when testing for the presence of an object in the current $scope/context.

`ng-if="!!someVar` or `ng-if="someVar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see performance gains if you were using purely JavaScript, but since you are already using The AngularJS `ng-if` [Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), I hardly think you need to worry about a performance difference between `ng-if="!!someVar"` and `ng-if="someVar"` to see if that object exists.

I'm sure you are also aware that `ng-if` is preferred over `ng-show`, so it's not as though `ng-if` is not recommended.

**Some resources:**

- [11 Tips to Improve AngularJS Performance](http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/)
- [Angular Performance: ng-show vs ng-if](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought there might be a difference in pure Javascript. Is there any resources you could recommend proving that in pure js `if (!!someObj)` is faster than `if (someObj)`

Comment: I don't know of a way to accurately calculate that. What I meant to say that you may see a performance gain using purely JavaScript **over** AngularJS Directives, but once you are using one or the other, the `!!someVar` vs `someVar` comparisons would perform identically. Logically, however, there is more to interpret by adding `!!`, but it's going to be so small that it won't change its performance.

Comment: So, I've done a simple test in C# since the Stopwatch can record in nanoseconds. **I know it's not JavaScript**, but this backs up the argument that you shouldn't worry. In 1,000,000 comparisons, just under 1/3 (let's say 310,000) of those comparisons showed "significant" differences (1+ nanoseconds) comparing `someVar` vs `!!someVar` (someVar being just a boolean in C#). Just over 1/3 (let's say 120,000) of those 310,000 comparisons show `!!someVar` was faster than comparing `someVar` by about 320 nanoseconds (on average). So... it doesn't really matter **in C#**, but does prefer `someVar`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had been theorising that maybe running `!!someVar` could be faster when `someVar` is quite large as it involves reading and evaluating more about the variable than `!!someVar`. `!!someVar` should literally only test for not null which might not always involve reading the variable from where-ever it's being stored -- though in JS it's probably always reading from memory.

Comment: If true, that is going beyond my knowledge of comparison logic in JavaScript. I speculate that `someVar` is being evaluated before `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters that much, but empty objects will still equate to a truthy value in javascript.

```
!!someVar === true;
```

Heres a plunk displaying the evaluation: [Plnkr here, open the console and run](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdxPBqojv07hDQwOqrUj?p=preview)

if you want the object to evaluate to false, use

```
Object.keys(someVar).length
```

Comment: Is the plnkr link correct? I don't see anything in it.